# St. Mary Magdalene meets Jesus in a garden Jn. 20:15, parallel to Song of Song's garden?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-john, reference-request, song-of-songs

Has any Catholic exegete ever noted the parallel between St. Mary Magdalene's meeting Jesus in a garden (cf. her mistaking Him as a gardener in [Jn. 20:15](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=20&l=15-#x)) with the garden of Solomon's Song of Songs? Or where Jesus is like the Bridegroom of Song of Songs and St. Mary Magdalene like the Bride?

Comment: It is usually compared with the garden of Eden from the book of Genesis, and his crucifixion taking place outside the walls of the holy city of Jerusalem with man's expulsion from paradise.

Comment: @Lucian Yes, but I'm focusing more on Jesus being like a Bridegroom in relation with St. Mary Magdalene being the Bride.